# How do I minimize taxes when transferring money to my wife and child?

Tags: united-states, taxes, loans, non-resident

I, as US non-resident, transferred some money from my US bank account into my wife's and son's US bank accounts. Some people say that it is classified as a gift and obligated for taxation, because we are aliens, not citizens. Well, citizens also pay gift taxes, but if the amount of gift is very huge (around 5 million dollars) I would like to know how to optimize this expense. Maybe I should file this transfer as a "family loan"? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a good question, but at the amounts you are talking about, you really need to talk to a paid tax professional/accountant, because the risk of getting bad advice online is too costly.

Comment: IANAL, but I think that money passing between spouses is treated as community property - that is, the money is considered to belong to both parties, so it's not in any sense a gift.

Comment: Being a non-citizen apparently does make a difference: [thebalance.com: Are Gifts to Your Spouse Taxable? It Depends](https://www.thebalance.com/are-gifts-to-your-spouse-taxable-it-depends-3505681)

Comment: To clarify: neither your wife nor your son are US citizens, but they live in the US? You say you are a US non-resident, so you are a US citizen that doesn't live in the US? Either way this is going to be pretty darn complicated, as there are so many rules between federal and state, alien and non-alien, that I can't even guess what the proper set of rules to go by will be in this case. And the countries they are citizens of - and the one you reside in - might all have their own ideas. Eek!

Comment: You're a US citizen, or not?

Comment: No, I am not US citizen. My wife and my son arrived there a couple of months ago. They are not US citizens, too.

Comment: http://www.sgrlaw.com/newsletter/newsletters/trusts_estates_trends/trustsnestatestrends_winter11/1622-2/

Comment: What if I lend them money instead of giving them as a gift?

Comment: To lend you must establish a legitimate loan contract. That means reasonable rates, terms and penalties for failure to repay. That must be followed up with financial evidence of repayment. You might be able to skirt it with small sums but the chance of audit increases with larger sums and anomalous behavior.

Comment: If you want to avoid tax implications simply do not deposit the money in an US situs account.

Comment: Bishop, what does it mean "US situs account"? I have already transferred money to their savings account.

Comment: A "US situs account" is an account held by a US company operating as a fiduciary.

Comment: @Alex: Why not make it a joint account?  Then it's not your money, or her money, but our money.  Again, I'm not a lawyer, but my friends who were non-US citizens at the time they married handled things this way, and never complained about tax problems.

Comment: In order to make a joint account I have to physically be in the US. I am not there.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming United States; rules may be wildly different elsewhere...

The "family loan" trick essentially lets you amortize a gift over multiple years of gift allowance and hopefully dodge gift tax, at the cost of having to pay income tax on the interest you must charge on the loan. The main advantage is that it lets you transfer all the money up front, rather than in $17,000-a-year-per-person-per-person chunks.

Let's take the normal case first. Any one person can give any one person up to a specified amount (currently $17k, I believe,) without incurring gift tax. Note that this is counted per person, not per household; you and your spouse could each give $17k per year to each of your son and his spouse under this rule, adding up to $68k per year total.

The family loan dodge consists of making them a loan of the money at the mandated minimum interest rate to make it a legal loan (something like 0.3% APR last time I looked), setting the repayment schedule so their payments each year including interest come out to less than you can gift them with tax-free, and then making that gift by paying (yourself) those payments on their behalf. You do need to pay income tax on the portion of those payments that represents interest income, but at that low rate this is a minor cost for the convenience.

You'd also want to set up your will to cover what happens if you die with them still owing money on the loan. And this, I believe, is where you will really need expert advice if you go this route, to minimize the government's cut at that time.

There may be better answers. If you are talking about this much money, ***you owe it to yourself to purchase expert advice from someone who has training and experience n this area, rather than taking free advice from the Internet that is likely to cost you much more in the long run.*** This is a situation where you can't afford *not* to hire a pro. (For example, I have no idea how trusts might or might not fit your needs.)

Comment: I think 17000$ exempt is for residents only. It is interesting, money I transferred is not a gift actually. My son gave me a power of attorney to sell his apartment which is not in the USA. I have to sell it and send money to him. I decided to transfer a part of money from my US account and the rest by wire transfer from abroad.

Comment: @Alex: **that's a very different question**. People assume that normally money in your account is your money, but if you sold _his property acting as his agent_ then it's already his money (just in your custody) not your money, so it's not a gift and nobody owes gift tax. _He_ may owe tax on the sale depending on lots of factors you haven't told us, and possibly you may be required to handle withholding payment for _his_ taxes. I strongly second keshlam's advice to consult an actual professional, _and tell them the whole story_.

Comment: Thank you, guys. Off-course,  I contact to the expert about this issue and get his professional advise. But before that I want to collect information as much as possible in order to make the best decision. BTW, who should I speak to? To the lawyer or to the accountant?

Comment: Dave, he is paying sales taxes in his home country where he sold his apartment. He is not an american citizen.